# How to write multiple log4net.Ext.Json appenders into the same log file

Tags: log4net

I am using [log4net-json](http://sourceforge.net/p/log4net-json/wiki/Home/) and have web app and another console project inside the same solution which both should log to the same file.

Here is my appender definition:

> ```
> <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
>   <file value="C:\logs\MyApp.log"/>
>   <appendToFile value="true"/>
>   <layout type='log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json'>
>     <decorator type='log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json' />
>     <default /> <!--explicit default members-->
>   </layout>
> </appender>
> ```

I have this same definition in both web app and in the console app.
But only logs from the web app are written into the log file. I have tried to use "MinimalLock" option but without success.

Any idea how to manage to have those 2 appenders to write to the same log file?

Comment: "only logs from the web app are written into the log file" - so do you see any logs from the console app if the web app is not running?

Comment: Yes, when running only console app then I can see log from  console app in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't, friendly advice. If you need to aggregate logs from multiple sources, your best bet would be local [nxlog](https://nxlog.co/) and you'd forward your logs to it over UDP or TCP. UDP has the benefit of freeing your app from logging burden, but you may loose some messages if system resources are exhausted.